# python 3.5 open() function won't work

Tags: python

Currently going through a course on Python which is using 2.7. I have 3.5 installed and have been able to translate thus far. I'm having problems with the open() function. For example: see script and result below.
[errno2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9ml1.png)

I have the file "textfile.txt" in the same folder as the .py file I'm running. As a check, I also put the file in the Python35 folder.. Any suggestions?

Comment: `import os` then `print(os.path.abspath('textfile.txt'))`. This will tell you what path is actually being used.

Comment: please don't link to your code on another site. Please include it and the error message in your question.

Comment: By the way, I notice that you have a file called `open.py`. This isn't what's causing the issue, but it's the sort of thing that _can_ cause issues. For example, making a module about math called `math.py` and then trying to `import math` somewhere. Overall, try to avoid naming your objects or files with names that already exist somewhere in Python.

Comment: Tigerhawk, did that and it shows that I'm looking in the correct folder.

Comment: Then are you sure the file's name is exactly `textfile.txt` and not something like `testfile.txt`?

Comment: @Bryan Oakley, what do you mean by "link to your code on another site"? The snapshot?

Comment: He means that you should paste the _text_ of both your script and the way you call it in the command line (with the error) into the question instead of linking to a screenshot. Also, a `dir` of the folder that holds your script and the text file might be helpful.

Comment: @Tigerhawk, yes. I even went as far as to edit the filename and copied that name from the explorer window in to the script. So it is literally the same.

Comment: So, the result of that `print()` was `C:\rdomingue\Python Programs\textfile.txt`? And you can enter that exact text into the command line and it opens the proper text file?

Answer (score 0):

"same folder as the .py file I'm running" -- `open()` will search relative to your current working directory, regardless of the `py` source file's location.

From [datamodel docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy):

> `__file__` is the pathname of the file from which the module was loaded, if it was loaded from a file

You can use `__file__` and `os.path.dirname()` to find the directory of the source file and from there look for the text file.

Comment: It looks like he's already navigated to the proper folder and then called the relative basename of the source file, so if the text file is in the same directory as the source file it should already be the correct working directory.